# Useful headless browser for Android

Tags: android, headless-browser

Is there any known headless browser that works on Android and supports JS? I tried HTMLUnit, but it doesn't work on Android. I tried using JSoup, wich works great but doesn't support JS. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What are you expecting a "headless browser" to do that `WebView` does not do?

Comment: I don't exactly know what WebView does? It is propably an UI component?

Comment: the idea what the headless browser is needed for is simple: for instance you want to do some automated actions on the website that doesn't have any API. For example, some website allows to edit maps but doesn't provide the api. The unofficial android app may user GPS coordinates instead of desktop coursor, but convert the GPS coordinates to the coursor coordinates the website accepts